# How to run next bash line even when set -e is switched

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Say I have something like this:

```
set -e;
echo 'doing some stuff'
false;
status=$?
post_hook send-message-elsewhere-with-status $status
```

One way to do what I want is:

```
set -e;
echo 'doing some stuff'
(
set +e
false;
status=$?
post_hook send-message-elsewhere-with-status $status
)
```

but is there some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not provide a lot of context to determine what it is you actually want to accomplish, but *man bash* is clear that with `set -e` your script will exit immediately when a non-zero exit status is received, *Except if the failing command is part of*:

- the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword;
- the test following the `if` or `elif` reserved words;
- any command  executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`;
- any command in a pipeline but the last; or
- if the command's return value is being inverted with the `'!'`.

So you have several option aside from a subshell to arrange your command as part of, to ensure the next line is executed if your command fails with a non-zero return

Comment: its basically for an after hook that always needs to run

Answer (score 0):

If there's a specific line to be made conditionally immune to `set -e`, this works:

```
false || true
```

This can be shortened to:

```
false || :
```

Or most cryptically:

```
false||:
```

If there's several lines, surround them in curly braces:

```
{ false; false; } || true
```

Note that `false` here represents a stand-in for any code that might return an error code.  Of course `false` prints no output; but something like `ls /bin/bash /bin/bbbbbbbash` would print to *STDOUT* and *STDERR*, and using the above method it still would.

**Or** surround the code to be made immune with `set` statements:

```
set +e; false ; set -e
```

---

Note:  the above methods work whether the lines in question return an error code or are successful.  If it's known that a specific line is certain to return an error, all that's needed is a leading `!`:

```
! false
```

Comment: np, yeah the last line that always needs to is an after hook